# Is there a way to access LetDefinitions from within the rspec formatter hooks?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I'm about to write a custom formatter for rspec where I have the need to access letDefinitions from within the formatter-hooks.

Given:

```
describe "Example" do
  let(:something) { "foo" }

  context "something to test" do
    # .....   
  end

end
```

In my formatter:

```
class MyFormatter
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self, :example_started

  def example_started(notification)
    @output << "Output of #{value_of_let(:something,notification)}"
  end

  private
  def value_of_let(what, notification)
    ### is there a way to find :something / 'foo' in notification?
  end
end
```

Comment: try just using it the way that you'd use it in a normal context-block... and see if it Just Works

Answer (score 0):

LetDefinitions are not directly accessible in the namespace of a running spec.
Meanwhile, I figured out how to complete the method *value_of_let* from the example above:

```
def value_of_let(what, notification)
   begin
     something  = notification.example.example_group_instance.send(what)
     something # => "foo"
   rescue
     # something is not defined for this example
     nil
   end
end
```